# Socket IO middleware for speific endpoints

Tags: socket.io, middleware

I know that with express http request you can add middleware to specific endpoints like so:

```
function someFunc(req, res, next) {
    // some stuff
    next()
}

app.get('/users', someFunc, (req, res) => { res.send('data stuff')})
```

I want to achieve something similar with SocketIO as all I found is using the `socket.use(fn)` function but this applies to all requests. I would like something like:

```
function someFunc(data, next) {
    // some stuff
    next()
}

socket.on('users', someFunc, data => {/*do something*/})
```

Any way to achieve this? Or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know there is not a way to do this but maybe you can just pass your data to that function with callback and use it like that?

```js
function someFunc(data, callback) {
    let passed = false;
    // do your stuff here with data.

    if (passed) {
        // passed data again to your callback or edited callback
        callback(data);
    }
}

socket.on("users", data => someFunc(data, callback));
socket.on("other", data => someFunc(data, callback));
...
socket.on("another", data => someFunc(data, (editedData) => {
    console.log(editedData);
}));
```

Maybe something like this you could use?

Comment: True, I also thought something like that would be the answer. i don't find it ideal though if you have multiple middlewares you want to insert sequentially, as they would all be nested. Just for like code readability purposes basically.

Comment: Yea i know it's really not ideal for multiple middlewares but for one it's quite okey. I think what we might do is check `.on()` function on `EventEmitter` and write on top of it as `express` do while binding functions

Comment: yeah, I went on the NodeJS github page and placed it as a feature request to be able to put multiple functions on the EventEmitter. But yes, I think overriding the function would be a temporary solution for now. Hopefully it can be implemented easy enough.

Comment: Oh how nice of you :). Maybe create a npm package for this purpose ? :)

Comment: maybe wrap all the middle functions into one and call the original .on() with the wrapped function

Comment: Also could be an option =)

Comment: Oh yeah. That would be a good idea actually. EventEmitter with middleware. Found a hole in the market :D

Comment: Let us know if you can finish it :)

Comment: Hi again, I found out that there is a `use` function on `socket`'s signature actually. `use(fn: (packet: Packet, next: (err?: any) => void) => void): Socket;` it goes like this. I'm trying to figure it out

Comment: it gives you a Packet data which is an array of eventName, packData, and another function called acknowledgement function, Idk what is function do, next is just to pass to function.

Comment: The problem with the `use` function is that it will go through that its given function for every request on every endpoint.

Comment: it is used like `socket.use((data, next) => { /*something with data*/; next()})`

Comment: I see, yea i saw while looking around =)

Comment: I added the feature request in node here https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/33932